# I want to create an icon for increasing/reducing coversize

Tags: icons

So I'm displaying a bunch of book covers from our library catalog (new additions), and I'd like an icon (well really two), that suggests changing the cover size. My other thought would be to have the small book on top of the bigger one. Or maybe some diagonal lines from the corners of the small to big book. Any suggestions for what might make a good icon to show this?
My initial foray (below) doesn't really do the job, at least not from the small sample of user testing I've done.

Increase cover size: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really want to just make the bigger image *bigger* you need to show that *some* aspects of the book are bigger - eg say it's a spiral bound book, you increase the number of spirals, make the cover bigger but keep the title the same size, so that the cover *looks* bigger.

eg: something like this:

[image] or this [image]

Comment: Do you mind if I use your arrow in my revised version?

Comment: Of course - no problem. I can add it at a larger size, or give you the SVG vector source file, if you wish so you can scale it to whatever size you need...

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to keep the icon small (http://www-test.mfrl.org/images/enlargecover2.png) so the one from the images above was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I always found the icon in Foxit Reader pretty clear for increasing the size, so I would think that decreasing the size would also look decent, just with the arrows pointing the opposite way.

[image]